# Is there a way track bandwidth over time like days, months?

Tags: monitoring, bandwidth

I would like to know how much bandwidth is being used on my server. Not HTTP bandwidth, but all protocols. Basically iftop data over time continuously logged. Then I could write a simple python script to process it and provide aggregate info.

Comment: Have you tried ntop?

Comment: Take a look at `vnstat`.

Comment: That looks promising, trying now

Comment: Are you already logging with sysstat's `sar`? You might have everything you need already.

Answer (score 4):

instead of writing it all new,
you could use tools like [cacti](http://www.cacti.net/).
With it you can analyze your network.

Answer (score 3):

I use [ntop](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/) for things like this.
There are a few ways you can store and generate reports with it.

Comment: I will look into this, I think I avoided ntop because it installed too much stuff.